# Yii Framework; How to check if a model attribute has a SPECIFIC validator?

Tags: forms, validation, yii

I am making a custom ActiveForm method, but it requires the model to have a certain custom validator attached the the attribute that is being passed through (otherwise who knows what will happen!?)

My question is simply... is there a way to run this check in the code that is reliable?

I don't want to add the validator at runtime.  That would create confusion and possibly let someone use this type of field where it ought not be used.

So I want to say something like:

```
if( model NOT HAVE validationMethod ON property)
  throw Exception;
```

Comment: Please elaborate... What do you mean exactly with "I don't want to add the validator at runtime."? Does this mean you don't want to use the `rules()` function of the model to set the validator? If you DO use the `rules()` function to set the validator you could (off course) just get the result of `$model->rules()` to check for the specific validator you are using on the given attribute/property.

Comment: I mean I don't want to add the validator in the place where I'm checking for it.  Yii lets you do that :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not sure why you want to do this, but in addition to viewing the rules array you can do:

`$model->getValidators($attribute)`

to check which validators are active for a particular attribute (or all attributes, if the arg is null. (I'm assuming $attribute = property in your example.)

This will return all the validator objects that are active for the current scenario and you can check if a predefined or custom class exists. It also gets you a bit more info than just the rules array (i.e., the properties of the validator class).

Comment: This did end up being the best solution, sadly.  I was really hoping for something a little more elegant than that... ah well.